# Cannot update class because it doesn't have an id field ORMLITE

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm having this exception:

```
09-05 17:10:41.947: W/System.err(2144): java.sql.SQLException: Cannot update class com.mauriciogiordano.commit.database.Commitment because it doesn't have an id field
```

Here is my Commitment class:

```
public class Commitment
{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, id = true)
    private int commitmentID;

    @DatabaseField
    private String description;

    private List<Commit> commits = null;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<Commit> getCommits() {
        return commits;
    }

    public void setCommits(List<Commit> commits) {
        this.commits = commits;
    }

    private void loadCommits(Context context) {

        DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        try {
            Dao<Commit, Integer> dao = dh.getCommitDao();

            commits = dao.queryForEq("commitmentID", commitmentID);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void newCommit(Long day, Context context) {      
        Commit commit = new Commit();

        commit.setWhen(day);
        commit.setCommitmentID(commitmentID);

        commits.add(commit);

        loadCommits(context);
    }

    public boolean hasCommitForToday(Long day, Context context) {
        if(commits == null) loadCommits(context);

        consecutiveDays++;
        return commits.contains(day);
    }

    public int getCommitmentID() {
        return commitmentID;
    }

    public void setCommitmentID(int commitmentID) {
        this.commitmentID = commitmentID;
    }

}
```

It seems to be everything OK.

Why I'm having this problem when I try to update a created object?

If I don't create the `commitmentID` attribute, how can I grab the auto-created `id` from the object?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are trying to perform the query? And, did you uninstall the app since the last change done in this class?

Comment: Instead of loadCommits() you can use `@ForeignCollectionField ForeignCollection<Commit> commits;`

Comment: Hi @Maurício! Have you found a cause of the issue?